# How to make the contents of an element with round-cornered border be also round-cornered?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/

I'm trying to get the white box itself to have rounded corners in addition to its transparent gray border using CSS3. Is this possible?

*html:*

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

*css:*

```
.outer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    
}

.inner{
    border-radius 5px;    
}
```

Bonus question:
What's with those black squares in the corners on Chrome?

EDIT: I found a discussion of the black squares: [Weird border opacity behavior in Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541120/weird-border-opacity-behavior-in-webkit/4541185)

Comment: If this question is to be useful to future searchers, it would be better to put the question code in the question and answer code in the answers, as all these jsfiddles will likely not stay put.

Comment: **edit** added the html/css in from jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/3/ maybe?

** **edit** **

[I prefer JamWaffles'](http://jsfiddle.net/5mMDy/2/):

```
.outer{
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color:white;
    padding: 5px;  
}
```

Or if you want [different looking corners](http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/13/) there's a variant of Jedidiah's:

```
.outer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: solid 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 10px; /*if you reduce this below 9 you will get black squares in the corners, as of Chrome 14.0.835.163 m*/
}

.inner{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I originally thought of this, however I deemed it a little too complex.

Comment: Now I check it in Chrome, I get black squares in the corners too... so actually I'd recommend using JamWaffles solution, or his advice and change the rgb to a color name or hexadecimal value, like: http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/8/

Comment: Whatchoo doin' stealing my rep! Kidding; good answer, and you need it more than me :-)

Answer (score 2):

JamWaffles answer is cleaner but if you did want to achieve this with the nested div tags and a translucent border you could set a background colour on the outer div to match the border colour, you would also need to set `background-clip: padding-box;` so that the border and background do not overlap.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/7/

css:

```
.outer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: solid 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.inner{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: [This works the same](http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/9/), is there a reason for including the `background-clip: padding-box;` for the outer and the `display:block;` for the inner?  (you can remove the `width: 100%;` as well)  I actually prefer this solution as it doesn't use the `position: relative;`, `left` and `top`.

Comment: @AJP The `background-clip` is for the transparency, in the original css @Muhd had the outer border 50% black, if you make the background color 50% black too you get an overlap behind the border. The other bits can come out.

Answer (score 1):

This will change the look of the box a bit, but if the border radius is greater than the width of the border, you'll get inner rounded corners too.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5mMDy/). I've removed the inner `div` as it's not needed for the example, as I have made the assumption you're nesting only to achieve the rounded effect.

In relation to the `black squares in the corners`, I don't get any at all with Chromium 12. You could try using a normal hex colour instead of an RGBA one. For your current colour, it's `#808080`, although I do appreciate the need for translucency; this is for a Facebox-style popup?

Comment: Yeah, it's for a popup.  Using your solution the black squares go away (I'm using Chrome 13).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/XjsWZ/10/

It seems like this would be a good solution although it technically doesn't use a border, it maintains the correct alpha value while getting rid of the black squares in webkit:

css:

```
.outer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: solid 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.inner{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```